# JqGrid is not filling with data

Tags: jquery, json, jqgrid

I have all the required javascript included, and the proper locale (at least, I think):

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="http://localhost/Web/Scripts/jqgrid/js/jquery.jqGrid.min.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="http://localhost/Web/Scripts/jqgrid/js/i18n/grid.locale-en.js"></script>
```

Here's the javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function() {
        //var url = 'http://' + window.location.hostname + '/Web/Service/Kpi/MonthlyGrid?orgName=' + orgName + '&month=3';
        var url = 'http://' + window.location.hostname + '/Web/Service/Kpi/MonthlyGrid';
        console.log(url);
        $.getJSON(url,
                    function(data) { console.log(data); });
        jQuery("#list").jqGrid({
            url: url,
            datatype: 'json',
            mtype: 'GET',
            colNames: ['ID','SITE_TYPE_ID', 'ORG_UNIT_ID', 'SITE_ID', 'AREA_ID', 'MONTH', 'YEAR', 'VALUE', 'IS_UNRELIABLE', 'CALCULATED_ON'],
            colModel: [
            { name: 'ID', index: 'ID', width: 40, align: 'left' },
          { name: 'SITE_TYPE_ID', index: 'SITE_TYPE_ID', width: 40, align: 'left' },
          { name: 'ORG_UNIT_ID', index: 'ORG_UNIT_ID', width: 40, align: 'left' },
          { name: 'SITE_ID', index: 'SITE_ID', width: 40, align: 'left' },
          { name: 'AREA_ID', index: 'AREA_ID', width: 40, align: 'left' },
          { name: 'MONTH', index: 'MONTH', width: 40, align: 'left' },
          { name: 'YEAR', index: 'YEAR', width: 40, align: 'left' },
          { name: 'VALUE', index: 'VALUE', width: 40, align: 'left' },
          { name: 'IS_UNRELIABLE', index: 'IS_UNRELIABLE', width: 40, align: 'left' },
          { name: 'CALCULATED_ON', index: 'CALCULATED_ON', width: 40, align: 'left'}],
            pager: jQuery('#pager'),
            rowNum: 10,
            rowList: [5, 10, 20, 50],
            sortname: 'ID',
            sortorder: "desc",
            viewrecords: true,
            imgpath: '/scripts/themes/coffee/images',
            caption: 'My first grid'
        });
    }); 
</script>
```

And lastly, the data returned from the URL:

```
{"page":1,"total":1,"records":6,"rows":
[{"id":"8F4CEED3-628E-9EE7-E040-000A3E0034B3","cell":["8F4CEED3-628E-9EE7-E040-000A3E0034B3","111","","","","3","2010","0.001597","1","9/16/2010 11:29:13 AM"]},
{"id":"8F4CEED3-628F-9EE7-E040-000A3E0034B3","cell":["8F4CEED3-628F-9EE7-E040-000A3E0034B3","","","","","3","2010","0.001597","1","9/16/2010 11:29:13 AM"]},
{"id":"8F4CEED3-6337-9EE7-E040-000A3E0034B3","cell":["8F4CEED3-6337-9EE7-E040-000A3E0034B3","111","","","","3","2010","0.013223","1","9/16/2010 11:29:07 AM"]},
{"id":"8F4CEED3-6338-9EE7-E040-000A3E0034B3","cell":["8F4CEED3-6338-9EE7-E040-000A3E0034B3","","","","","3","2010","0.013223","1","9/16/2010 11:29:08 AM"]},
{"id":"8F4CEED3-63E0-9EE7-E040-000A3E0034B3","cell":["8F4CEED3-63E0-9EE7-E040-000A3E0034B3","111","","","","3","2010","0.008352","1","9/16/2010 11:29:17 AM"]},
{"id":"8F4CEED3-63E1-9EE7-E040-000A3E0034B3","cell":["8F4CEED3-63E1-9EE7-E040-000A3E0034B3","","","","","3","2010","0.008352","1","9/16/2010 11:29:17 AM"]}]}
```

Where have I gone wrong?

Comment: looks ok so far, need to see your HTML and are you including jQuery?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems the error is the order of js files. You have to include grid.locale-en.js before jquery.jqGrid.min.js. With the correct order of the JavaScript files your grid can be displayed as [following](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/JsonChrisMcCall.htm). (I changed only width of some columns and remove [deprecated](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3aupgrade_from_3.4.x_to_3.5) `imgpath` parameter).